# BTRFS: problems with raid1?

Tags: btrfs

btrfs df / report this

```
btrfs filesystem df  /
Data, RAID1: total=4.26TiB, used=4.16TiB
System, RAID1: total=8.00MiB, used=752.00KiB
System, single: total=32.00MiB, used=0.00B
Metadata, RAID1: total=7.00GiB, used=5.98GiB
Metadata, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
WARNING: Multiple block group profiles detected, see 'man btrfs(5)'.
WARNING:   Metadata: single, raid1
WARNING:   System: single, raid1
```

I need to rebalance fs or what to clear the warning messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, I only need to rebalance

```
btrfs balance start --bg -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /
```

now seems fine, the warning message disappear

```
btrfs filesystem df /
Data, RAID1: total=4.14TiB, used=4.07TiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=608.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=6.00GiB, used=5.16GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```